# Cascading Properties in Entity Framework via Repository Pattern

Tags: entity-framework

Say I have a class Person that has an "IsArchived" property.  A Person can have a Collection - each of which can also be Archived.

Right now I have an UpdatePerson method in my repository that looks like this:

```
    public Person UpdatePerson(Person person)
    {
        _db.Persons.Attach(person);
        var entry = _db.Entry(person);
        entry.Property(e => e.Name).IsModified = true;
        entry.Property(e => e.Friends).IsModified = true;
        SaveChanges();
        return entry.Entity;
    }
```

And I have a separate Repository method for Archive:

```
    public void ArchivePerson(int personId)
    {
        var person = _db.Persons.FirstOrDefault(c => c.PersonId == personId);
        if (person != null)
        {
            person.IsArchived = true;

            foreach (var friend in person.Friends)
            {
                ArchivePerson(friend.PersonId);
            }

            SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

This means that from my WebAPI, I have to dedicate a function to Archiving/Unarchiving.  It would be cool if I could just call Update and set the Archived for the given entity, and apply this to all child entities where possible.  Is there any way to accomplish this, or am I best off sticking to the ArchivePerson repository method?